# On my Android Studio my Gradle Sync is Not Showing up in File Menu to Sync Project with Gradle Files

Tags: android, android-studio

On my Android Studio my Gradle Sync is not Showing Up in File Menu to Sync Project with Gradle Files

[image: screenshot of Android Studio]

Why is it not showing up? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your project may have error so that It not showing the Gradle sync option

Comment: Highly likely you've opened the wrong folder. You may also try to build it manually from the command line but it can be difficult using windows.